# Rotation sometimes snaps in one axis when the arrow keys are released

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I am usign the new inputSystem to rotate the player to face the direction of movement and it is working fine, but when I release the arrow keys the rotation snaps to one of the axis inputs. Here is my class:

```
public class Rotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Control _control;
    private Vector3 _axisValue;
    private bool _pressedButton;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _control = new Control();    
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(_pressedButton) RotateBasedOnInputAxis();
    }

    private void RotateBasedOnInputAxis()
    {
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(_axisValue.x, _axisValue.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, angle, 0);
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        SubscribeRotationHandlerToMovement();
        SubscribePressedButtonToMovement();
        _control.Player.Movement.Enable();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        UnsubscribeRotationHandlerToMovement();
        _control.Player.Movement.Disable();
    }

    private void SubscribeRotationHandlerToMovement()
    {
        _control.Player.Movement.started += RotationHandler;
        _control.Player.Movement.performed += RotationHandler;
        _control.Player.Movement.canceled += RotationHandler;
    }

    private void SubscribePressedButtonToMovement()
    {
        _control.Player.Movement.performed += context => _pressedButton = true;
        _control.Player.Movement.canceled += context => _pressedButton = false;
    }
    
    private void UnsubscribeRotationHandlerToMovement()
    {
        _control.Player.Movement.started -= RotationHandler;
        _control.Player.Movement.performed -= RotationHandler;
        _control.Player.Movement.canceled -= RotationHandler;
    }

    private void RotationHandler(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        _axisValue = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    }
}
```

In order to solve it I have created a bool (_pressedButton) to check if there is any input, if not the rotation should not change. It works sometimes but I couldn't find a pattern for this. Maybe it is because of the sequence of events, I still working on that, but I would aprreciate some help.